# Which filetype to import and manage easily in C#

Tags: c#, automated-tests, ranorex

I am a beginner concerning development in C# and I need your advice to help me choosing a practical fileformat whose content will be imported in my application.

Basically I'm developing test automation with Ranorex, a test automation software whose projects are based on C#.

The aim of the specific project is to test another software which imports a file containing a list of devices and repeats this procedure 
I want to see if the devices are each time successfully imported. It is like a big loop where Ranorex restarts the program again and again with another file to import and other devices from a file.

So I have several files to import with various devices inside it.
The problem is the number is not regular.

My first idea was to use an excel file like that but importing excel in C# does not seem practical.

[image]

Our program can only import file by file and needs to be restarted after checking the devices.
Basically I want my C# (ranorex) project to start my software, import a file, check every devices from this file, close the software and restart it again the same way.
You understand it is more or less a question of list with two dimension.

The list will contains the file to import and each file contains devices to test.
What is the best solution to do that ? A database ?

edit1: Well my first picture was very basic and was there to help you understand.
In reality, my lines are like this, The MHZ is the file and the other colons are a description of one device. You see why I believe XML will be perhaps complicated to manage, because a device is characterized by many parameters.
[image]

Comment: While I agree with the answers and comments. Just for completeness and for the casual reader - using Excel files in C# is not such a big deal  (if you are working with Windows and Office).

Comment: Yep the testing area is exclusively on Win 7 and use Office. That's why I thought about Excel, because everybody is able to fill and add some lines easily in an Excel file. But the difference with xlsx, xls formats and every solutions I found (COM, open xml sdk, Ado.NET) totally lost me..

Comment: Well, this is not a recommendation - it really depends on your workflow and on your coworkers in the testing area. You might want to look into Excel automation using the interop assemblies. XML is most likely better for you (as the programmer), but if the end users have a problem with XML - your job might be to provide an other solution and in that case I would check out the Excel automation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what the [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file format is for. There are tons of articles on XML Serialization using .NET, I recommend you start with [Introducing XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and work your way through the examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about it but the problem is the list will be updated and completed frequently. XML is not very easy to read if there are lots of elements and I don't know if it is easy to manage to add elements ? 
I am in developing for an enterprise so we have license for SQL manager etc..

Comment: I would say this isn't what XML is designed for really.  XML is a *markup language* designed for marking up text--not defining arbitrary data.  While I agree that it would work fairly well for this situation you could just as well use CSV or INI-style files for such a straightforward use case.

Comment: XML was created with that very purpose in mind; to be easily read by both humans and machines.

Comment: There are many ways to display XML you could use CSS to style the XML output directly or even use an XSLT to transform it into a HTML. @RonWarholic Although it is essentially a markup language I have to emphasise the **extensible** part of it, I would argue the actual design goals of XML extend far beyond that e.g. interoperability/data exchange and describing data.

Comment: And is it practical to complete ? If people in the testing area want to add new filenames with some devices, is it as clear as a SQL table ?

Comment: @xenom going by your example your XML should be pretty simple & easy to edit. There are a few XML Editors out there which could make their life a bit easier. You could even go as far as writing an XSD for it and use an editor which validates the data before saving.

Comment: I am installing XMLPad right now. I'll see if it is simple enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

*.xml is good enough.
*.txt is enough if just want a something like *.ini file with lists delimited by "," which is simplier.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't data driven testing, supported by Ranorex, exactly what you want to do?
http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-3-data-driven-testing.html

Just create two variables within your Ranorex repository, and set up one for the file column and one for the device column of your Excel table.

Comment: Normally yes, but I already asked my question on the support forum and data driven with excel needs to know how many values the variable will have. The problem here is that the imported file will constantly change and get new lines and devices. Finally it is not so effective and working with C# is better.

Comment: I don't see where you have to know the number of values for your variables. If you follow the link above, you can read through the doc, where is explained, how Ranorex uses Excel file as Input data and that variables will be assigned dynamically. I also read through your posting on Ranorex support, and I think there is some misunderstanding! When I find some time, I'm gonna explain you my suggestion to solve this.

Comment: I already asked the support forum about this and I obviously read this link about 5 times :) the problem is that for each file name I must import the corresponding devices. And everything must be done chronologically : start the soft, import the file, load every devices in the file, close the soft, repeat again and again for each file. But, this is not possible natively with Ranorex tools, even data driven. It is working if I work only with filename or only with devices colon but not both at the same time.